# buefy's b-table not updating upon clicking the delete icon or add row button?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I am currently using the Vue js framework along with buefy (0.9.2) for the UI components. The issue here is that the b-table component is not updating sometimes when I click the delete icon(deletes that row from the table) or when I click the add new row button. I can confirm that the operations(delete and add row) themselves are working perfectly. I mean I console logged the data array and I can see that the array of objects is updated. The issue is that the front-end screen or b-table component is not immediately updating or re-rendering. This issue is however not consistent though. (sometime's it works and sometimes it doesn't).

**NOTE: If I go back to the previous page and do a hard refresh(ctrl+f5) and then return back to the same page again then the issue is not there anymore which makes me think that this is some kind of cache-related issue where the page is not updating sometimes.**

How can I solve this inconsistent issue?

I have also tried adding a key prop like  :key="componentKey" to the b-table and then incrementing the key by 1, whenever the delete or add button is clicked. But this solution is not a proper one as it comes with its own set of problems. For example, I am using pagination with my table and let say if I click the delete or add button on the 3rd page then since I am manually refreshing the table by incrementing the key the table will restore back to the 1st page.

My vue page-

```
<template>
  <div class="container is-fluid">
    <b-loading :is-full-page="true" :active.sync="this.isLoading"></b-loading>
    <p class="subtitle">Bank Account Detail</p>
    <b-field label="ID">
      <b-input
        :disabled="true"
        :value="this.objectData.id"
        
      ></b-input>
    </b-field>
    <b-button @click="addTableRow('records', 'records')" class="is-radiusless">Add Bank Record</b-button>
     <!-- Begin Code Change:-Fixed delete row issue by refreshing table after adding key prop to the b-table-8-27-2020-vignesh --> 
    <b-table
      ref="records"
      :data="this.objectData.records"
      :hoverable="true"
      :paginated="true"
      :per-page="10"
      selectable
      @select="selected"
      detailed
      :show-detail-icon="true"
      icon-pack="mdi"
    >  
     <!-- End  Code Change:-Fixed delete row issue by refreshing table after adding key prop to the b-table-8-27-2020-vignesh -->   
    
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props" field="effectiveDate" label="Eff Date">{{ props.row.effectiveDate }}</b-table-column>
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props" field="accountType" label="Account Type">{{ props.row.accountType }}</b-table-column>
        <b-table-column   v-slot="props">
          <b-button class="is-borderless is-borderless" @click="deleteTableRow('records','records',props.index)">
            <b-icon icon="delete"></b-icon>
          </b-button>        
        </b-table-column>     
    
      <template slot="detail" slot-scope="props">
        <div class="container is-fluid">
          <b-field label="Effective Date">
            <b-datepicker
              :value="props.row.effectiveDate | toDate"
              @input="(newValue)=>{updateRowValue('records', props.index, 'effectiveDate', newValue)}"
              editable
            ></b-datepicker>
          </b-field>
          <b-field label="Account Type">
            <b-input
              :value="props.row.accountType"
              @input="(newValue)=>{updateRowValue('records', props.index, 'accountType', newValue)}"
            >
           </b-input>
          </b-field>
         
     <b-field label="Country">
        <b-autocomplete
          :value="props.row.country"
          :open-on-focus="true"
          :keep-first="true"
          :data="['India','United Kingdom','United States']"
          @input="(newValue)=>{updateRowValue('records', props.index, 'country', newValue)}"
          >
          <template slot="empty">No results found</template>
        </b-autocomplete>                          
      </b-field>


         <b-field label="Bank Name">
          <b-input
            :value="props.row.bankName"
            @input="(newValue)=>{updateRowValue('records', props.index, 'bankName', newValue)}"
          ></b-input>
        </b-field> 

         <b-field label="Branch Name">
          <b-input
            :value="props.row.branchName"
            @input="(newValue)=>{updateRowValue('records', props.index, 'branchName', newValue)}"
          ></b-input>
        </b-field>  


        <b-field label="Bank Account Number">
          <b-input
            :value="props.row.bankAccountNumber"
            @input="(newValue)=>{updateRowValue('records', props.index, 'bankAccountNumber', newValue)}"
          ></b-input>
        </b-field>

        <b-field label="IFSC">
          <b-input
            :value="props.row.ifsc"
            @input="(newValue)=>{updateRowValue('records', props.index, 'ifsc', newValue)}"
          ></b-input>
        </b-field>                    
                                                                        
        </div>
      </template>
    </b-table>
    <section>
      <p class="is-size-7 has-text-danger">{{submitError}}</p>      
      <b-button @click="submitForm" class="is-radiusless">Submit</b-button>
      <b-button type="is-text" @click="$router.go(-1)" class="is-radiusless">Return</b-button>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { viewMixin } from "../viewMixin.js";
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import api from "../store/api";
const ViewName = "BankAccountDetails";
export default {
  name: "BankAccountDetails",     
  mixins: [viewMixin(ViewName)],  
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      isFetching: false      
    };
  },
  computed: {
    
    newRecord() {
      return this.$route.params.id === null;
    },
    filteredCountryList() {
      return this.listCountry.filter(option => {
        return option
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.objectData.countryOfBirth.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      var idCopy=this.$route.params.id
    /* if incoming route has an ID, query for api object */
            if (this.viewData.route_param) {
                if (this.$route.params.id != null) {
                    var query = {
                        key: this.viewData.api_id,
                        path: this.viewData.api_path + this.$route.params.id,
                        overwriteData: false
                    };
                    
                     this.$store.dispatch(this.viewData.mounted_action, query).then(data => {
                       this.objectData.id = this.$route.params.id;
                        if (data.length == 0)   //if length of response is empty then set id to null in order to do a post on submit
                        {
                          this.$route.params.id=null;
                        }
                    }
                    ).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err)
                      })
                  
                }
            } else {
                var query = {
                    key: this.viewData.api_id,
                    path: this.viewData.api_path,
                    overwriteData: false
                };
                this.$store.dispatch(this.viewData.mounted_action, query);
                this.objectData.id = this.$route.params.id;
            }
            //this.$store
    this.objectData.id=idCopy
  },
  methods: {

 deleteTableRow(tableRef, dataCol, index) {
                this.objectData[dataCol].splice(index, 1);   

            },

    writeLog(option) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(option));
    },
                           
  },
  components: {}
};
</script>
```

I am not really sure if this is an issue with buefy's b-table component or if it has sometime to do with the vue js. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `custom-row-key` as a prop to your b-table ([docs](https://buefy.org/documentation/table/#api-view)) with a unique key of objectData.records, e.g.

```
<b-table
  ref="records"
  :data="this.objectData.records"
  :hoverable="true"
  :paginated="true"
  :per-page="10"
  selectable
  @select="selected"
  detailed
  :show-detail-icon="true"
  icon-pack="mdi"
  custom-row-key="id"
>
```